# Installing keycloak with helm chart using existing postgres

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I have an existing postgres-ha up and running installed using [bitnami helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql-ha).
This postgres has loadbalancer and has the port opened to access from external.

Now, I want the keycloak to be installed using this existing postgres as persistent store.
First I added the repo as

```
helm repo add codecentric https://codecentric.github.io/helm-charts
```

then I tried to follow the [ReadMe](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak) steps,

```
helm install --name keycloak codecentric/keycloak
```

and I keep getting the error

> Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: postgresql.
> In the steps it is mentioned as postgres as default a

This happens even without any changes to the [default values](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/keycloak/values.yaml).
Can someone points to, how to resolve thi?
Thanks.

Comment: can you check running `helm dep update` before `helm install` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone got the same issue, I followed the post [here](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/issues/52) and issues a helm update command

```
helm dependency update helm-charts/charts/keycloak
```

and that resolved the issue.